# ReferenceError: window is not defined at e2e test

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm writing a new e2e test using TS + Puppeteer and I need to scroll a page down, to click on a button.

```
it('user create request at homepage', async () => {
    await page.goto(`${global.HOST}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    const postRequestBtn = 'qa-id="dummybtn"';
    await window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    //also tried await window.scrollTo(0,100);
    await page.waitForSelector(postRequestBtn);
});
```

I expect to scroll the page down, but it catches an error: 
    `ReferenceError: window is not defined` - can you please say,what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `page.evaluate` function to execute javascript in the page context.

**Scroll to the element:**

`await page.$eval('qa-id="dummybtn"', el => el.scrollIntoView());`

**Scroll to the bottom:**

`await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight));`

Comment: Your first code will not work if jQuery is not present on the page. Also, `scrollIntoView` will likely not work (even if jQuery is present) as the element does not seem to exist as OP is using `waitForSelector`. Therefore, you might want to remove the first code snippet. Also, maybe give some more context about `page.evaluate`, then you have a solid answer :)

Comment: I tried first one but it isn`t work for me. I'll try second solution and let you know, thanks for your reply!